# Django returns 500 instead of 401 / 403 when no token passed

Tags: python, django

I have a Django view that requires a user to be authenticated (The app uses jwt),
When the request is being passed without any Authorization header the response is 500, I want it to be 401 / 403 because it should not return an internal server error but an unauthorized error.

I searched a lot and could not find a way to customize this behavior

Here is the code:

views.py:

```
class GetProfileAPIView(APIView):
permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

def get(self, request):
    user = self.request.user
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(user_profile, context={"request": request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "apps.users.serializers.CreateUserSerializer,",
        "user": "apps.users.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "current_user": "apps.users.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "user_delete": "djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer",
    },
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    )
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": (
        "Bearer",
        "JWT",
    ),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=120),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "SIGNING_KEY": "supersecretkey~!",
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the permission_classes like following:

```
class HLogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, partial(IsAllowed, 'WCloud_HLog')]
```